# I cannot find .asoundrc in the home directory, does it exist in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So I'm trying to configure my laptop's PulseAudio so that I can record my microphone and from my sound card at the same time. Every tutorial says that I need to make edits to the `.asoundrc` file.

After some searching I found that the `.asoundrc` should be located in my home directory. Searching my home directory I do not find the file at all.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and it was a fresh install, not an upgrade from a previous version. Does 14.04 actually use this file? Why is it not here? Can I create the file manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.asoundrc` is not created by default. This file is only used to add user-specific parameters as you want to do now. So yes, you can create it manually. You can find more info in [the ALSA project wiki.](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#The_.asoundrc_file_format)